# How to get the combinations, only with multiplicative principle?

Tags: probability

If i have a permutation with repetition, like:

> How many words can i formed with the word ABANA

Then, with the formula of $P_{rep}$ $\frac{5!}{3!} = 20$,

Ok its easy to me with the formula, but how could it be done only with the multiplicative principle? Since I have read that most of the formulas (combination / variation / permutation) come from these principles. Do you also know any text that explains the exercises only with these principles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are five positions to fill with a B, an N, and three As.  The B can be placed in five ways, and the N can be placed in one of the remaining positions in four ways.  There is only one way to fill the final three positions with As since the As are indistinguishable.  Hence, there are $5 \cdot 4 = 20$ distinguishable arrangements of the letters of the word ABANA.

Answer (score 3):

The total number of ways to arrange this word is 5!=120.

But since there are 3 'A's, we've counted everything 6 times.

Thus, $\frac{120}{6}=20$, as desired.

Comment: How do you guess, that having three 'A', we count everything 6 times?

Comment: @Mattiu Because there are 3!=6 ways to arrange 3 'A's.